# What is the newest version of IIS that SharePoint 2013 Foundation can run

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, iis

What is the newest version of IIS that SharePoint 2013 Foundation can run? The server is currently on Server 2012 and 2012 can run IIS 10 as far as i was able to determine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Server 2012 R2 is the newest version of Windows Server that SharePoint 2013 with SP1 can utilize.

Windows Server 2012 R2 has IIS 8.5.

Comment: We do not have the licences to use 2012 r2, only 2012.

Comment: IIS is an integral component of Windows Server. You cannot change the version.

Comment: its been a while since i last worked with servers, 2008 r2? i think. anywho thanks for that.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 comes with IIS 8. 2008 R2 comes with IIS 7.5.